# Laravel Query Builder with 2 tables

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have next sentence in raw:

```
SELECT last_operation FROM policies
        INNER JOIN(users) 
        ON (policies.user_id=users.id)
        group by (user_id);
```

And works correctly. But when I transcript to query builder nodt throw any error but results doesnt good:

```
$lastOperationUser = DB::table('policies')
                  ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'policies.user_id')
                  ->select('last_operation','user_id')
                  ->groupBy('user_id');
```

I have "one-to-many" relationship.

One user may have a infinite number of policies but one policy only can belongs one user.

In this sentence I try to obtain an array with the newest policy for each user which I get through the "last_operation" field (type data field).

```
USERS         POLICIES
id            id
name          last_operation
              id_user
```

If I execute dd($lastOperationUser);  I obtain:

```
         Builder {#552 ▼
            +connection: MySqlConnection {#219 ▶}
            +grammar: MySqlGrammar {#220 ▶}
            +processor: MySqlProcessor {#221}
            +bindings: array:6 [▶]
            +aggregate: null
             +columns: array:2 [▶]
             +distinct: false
             +from: "policies"
             +joins: array:1 [▶]
             +wheres: array:1 [▶]
             +groups: array:1 [▶]
             +havings: null
             +orders: null
             +limit: null
             +offset: null
             +unions: null
             +unionLimit: null
             +unionOffset: null
             +unionOrders: null
             +lock: null
             +operators: array:29 [▶]
             +useWritePdo: false
           }
```

Can I use Eloquent?
Any help?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the query:

```
...->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

Comment: If I do taht change I obtain an error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'test.policies.last_operation' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `last_operation`, `user_id` from `policies` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `policies`.`user_id` where `admin` = 0 group by `user_id`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this way. you not have to use "GroupBy" in controller.
and the code will be like:

```
$lastOperationUser = DB::table('policies')
                  ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'policies.user_id')
                  ->get();
```

And if you want to short by latest post, you can do that on blade(in looping)
for example code will be like:

```
@forelse($lastOperationUser->reverse()->slice(0, 1) as $content)
```

I always use this simply way, and its work

Comment: But I need just the user with his newest last_operation to show with each user datas

Comment: if you mean you just need 1 latest data, you cant add more att in blade like this @forelse($lastOperationUser->reverse()->slice(0, 1) as $content)

Comment: I need a relationship between two tables. users & policies. when I show users data I need show the lastes last_operation field. This field is in policies table.  One to many relationship. You can check the model in my question

Comment: I think it will work with added ->slice(0, 1) in foreach